# AWS Glue metrics to populate Job name, job Status, Start time, End time and Elapsed time

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, aws-data-pipeline

I tried various metrics options using glue.driver.* but there is no clear way to get  Job name, job Status, Start time, End time and Elapsed time in Cloudwatch metrics. This info is already available under Job Runs history but no way to get this on Metrics.

I found few solutions where this can be achieved using Lambda function but there should be an easy way.

Please share ideas. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. In order to track glue job runs we ended up writing a small shell script which transformed the JSON Output of -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/list-jobs.html to CSV. The final Output resembled the following :

[image]

Comment: that's an awesome idea, I will check on how can I push this to metric as I want to create a graph showing Job name, job Status, Start time, End time and Elapsed time

Comment: @Sam, please upvote if you were able to implement the above workaround